# Problem adding two numbers in a quantum computer with Drapper's algorithm

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, arithmetic

I would like to add numbers. In this simple example a = 1 and b = 1.
The circuit I created looks like this:
[image]

We have two registers a and b. Both have a size of 3 qubits. I'm using Big Endian notation, so for example the bit array [1, 1, 0] = 6.
I start with encoding both numbers by adding a X-Gate to qubit 2 and 5.
After that I follow Drapper's algorithm for integer addition: QFT on a, Evolve a by b. QFT-Inverted on a.

However the result is wrong that I'm getting at the end: The state 17 (= [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]) has probability 1. I would like to see state 2 with probability 1 obviously.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding your output.  All quantum calculations must be reversible.  Having two 3-bit inputs yield a six-bit output is not reversible.

The result you're actually seeing is the three-bit result $[0, 1, 0]$ corresponding to the sum and the three-bit result $[0, 0, 1]$ which is the second argument.  This is reversible, and you could rederive your original $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are just interpreting your output the wrong way. The result of the addition will *only* be in register `a` as a 3-qubit result. You are evolving `b` over into `a`. If you only look at your top 3 qubits, they are in the state [0, 1, 0] which corresponds to decimal 2, which is the correct output.

You can verify this by modifying the input values in `a` and `b` in [0, 3], but please account for the carry (in essence, since you reserved 3 qubits for `a`, in effect you only have 2 qubits available to specify values 0 to 3 inclusive).

For reference, I have the corresponding code [here](https://github.com/qcc4cp/qcc/blob/main/src/arith_quantum.py).